# Set Internet Explorer options for protractor tests

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, protractor

I would like to set in my protractor configuration the default language also for internet explorer, but I cannot find antying retalted to this. They only say how to do it in Chrome and Firefox: [Adding chrome and Firefox specific options](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options).

This is what I have so far:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['lang=de']
        }
    },
    {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'args': ['lang=de']
        }
    },
    {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
    }
]
```

So how do I add the 'args' option to IE aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it wont work for IE browser, We need to change it manually.

This is because IE is storing the language selection in the registry, something that Selenium isn't going to have access to modify. Firefox and Chrome don't use the registry, which is why you can modify their language settings more easily.